# MAMP PRO Can't Find WebStart

Tags: mamp-pro

I've upgraded from MAMP PRO v2 to v3. Now MAMP PRO can't find WebStart. My browser is going to `http://localhost/MAMP/?language=English` but can't find a page there?

What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 1):

By default MAMP runs on port 8888 so you need to go to

http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English

Answer (score 0):

You may already have found a solution. Anyway, 
two things to check:
**MAMP**
MAMP PRO -> Settings -> Webstart

**Apache**
httpd.conf
ServerRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library"
DocumentRoot "MAMP_DocumentRoot_MAMP"

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that my servers weren't started. If anyone else stumbles upon the same problem...